# How to auto change one input field value by changing another field value using JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There are two input fields `total_amount` & `delivery_charge`.

`total_amount` field already have a value, now I want that when I input some value into `delivery_charge` field that will change the `total_amount` field's value.

Suppose `total_amount` field's value is `200`.

Now I input `20` into `delivery_charge` field and that will effect the `total_amount` field and the value will be `220`.

For any type of changes of `delivery_charge` field it will change the value of `total_amount` field.

But for myself it will not change perfectly.

Suppose `total_amount` is `200`

when input `delivery_charge` = `2`

`total_amount` = `202`

when input `delivery_charge` = `20`

`total_amount` = `2020`

Here is my code detail

**html**

```
<h4>Grand Total : <input type="number" id="total_amount" readonly class="form-control total_amount" value="0.00"></h4>

<input type="text" name="delivery_charge" id="delivery_charge" class="form-control">
```

**js**

```
$('#delivery_charge').keyup(function(event) {
            var total_amount = $('.total_amount').val();
            var delivery_charge = $(this).val();
            var grand_total_amount = total_amount + delivery_charge;
            $('.total_amount').val(grand_total_amount);
});
```

Anybody help please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this solution.

1. Store the `total_amount` so that you could have the original value when we update it on delivery changes.
2. Use `parseInt()` to make sure the value you got is not a string.

```js
const total_amount = parseInt($('.total_amount').val());

$('#delivery_charge').keyup(function() {
  $('.total_amount').val(total_amount + parseInt($(this).val() || 0));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Grand Total :
  <input type="number" id="total_amount" readonly class="form-control total_amount" value="200"></h4>

<input type="number" name="delivery_charge" id="delivery_charge" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Just edit the `delivery_charge` to have `0` when the input is empty.

Comment: can't work yet....after using your code while I input any value in `delivery_charge` field only that value is showing into `total_amount` field.

Comment: `total_amount` can't store

Comment: @ArafatRahman did you run the snippet in the answer?  It works as described.   If you're code does not work, then you've not copied/implemented the answer correctly.

Comment: @freedomn-m...I just copied the code....but not working.....total amount can't store the actual value....in @phucbm code `total_amount` has fixed value....but in my code `total_amount` is continueously changing not fixed

Comment: In what case the `total_amount` is continuously changing? Could provide more specific input and output, please?

Comment: it is a purchase screen.... this `total_amount` field is continuously changing according to purchase item. this `total_amount` field value is also set with another JS file. if new item added `total_amount` will be change

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you are dealing with numbers, use parseInt() (or parseLong() if you are dealing with huge numbers) as following

```
$('#delivery_charge').keyup(function(event) {
            var total_amount = parseInt($('.total_amount').val());
            var delivery_charge = parseInt($(this).val());
            var grand_total_amount = total_amount + delivery_charge;
            $('.total_amount').val(grand_total_amount);
});
```